# Simulated Annealing Algorithm Steps

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms

I just learned about simulated annealing and I am trying to work through coding a minimization problem in R using this technique, but there are some holes in my knowledge and I have a few questions.

I think I understand the general premise behind the algorithm steps: we always accept E_new if it is less than E_old. If E_new is greater than or equal to E_old then we generate a random Unif(0,1) number and if U is less than or equal to exp[-(E_new - E_old)/T], we accept the new energy state. If that's not correct then please correct me.

What I am confused about is how to implement this in R. How do I tell R what E_new and E_old are? Where do those values come from?

When I initialize the problem, I am supposed to set an initial temperature T_0. I understand that part. But am I also supposed to be creating some expression to create an initial value for E_old? I'm just not sure how I insert the energy levels at each iteration into this simulation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This seems a coding, rather than mathematics, question. Did you check [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84688/simulated-annealing-in-r), for instance?

Comment: You need a method to randomly generate a new candidate for the next state, and then the two energies are just the energies of the current state and the candidate state. This part of the method is problem-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, Miguel. I'm not following it 100% but it's definitely helping me get closer to understanding.